# How do I filter the data source list based on property value defined in the rule if clause

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules, codeeffects

How do I filter the source list based on property value defined in the rule if clause?
for e.g, I bound the two properties with the data source list,

1st Property "Word" Bound with English Word/Arabic Word/Spanish Word.

2nd Property "Fee" Bound with English Word Fee/ Arabic Word Fee/ Spanish Word Fee

Now If the word is equal to English Word then filter the fee property to English Word Fee only.

Answer (score 0):

I guess in Code Effects rule editor it would be as simple as this:

```
If Word is English then set Fee to English Fee
Else if Word is Spanish then set Fee to Spanish Fee
Else set Fee to Arabic Fee
```

Comment: Actually, I want to restrict the Fee Source list Item specific to the Word Type. In my scenario Fee is bound to 3 Fee types, user can select any fee type from source list but I want if word is English he should select only English Fee type.

Comment: Could you give an example of a rule in free form you are trying to create?